# Gigantic numbers are being put into my array and other calculations. Cannot figure out why?

Tags: c, arrays

I'll start off by saying i'm brand new to C and trying to learn it for a class. I need to create an integer array and put slots 29 to the EOF(of the file) into it. I also need to count how many slots there are after the 29th slot. Sorry if that is confusing, I am confused myself...

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    /*returns integer using main with return(0) below */
    int main()
    {

    /* Declare fp */
    FILE *fp;

    /* Initiates array "str" with 29 elements  and initiated other needs variables*/
    char str[29];
    int array[20];
    int size;
    int i=0;

    /* opens binary file for reading */
    fp = fopen("draft.myext" , "rb");

    /* Fills "str" character array with 29 characters from the file. */
    fgets(str, 29, fp);

    /* Makes an array of a max of 20 after the 29 we already used */
    fread(array, sizeof(int), 20, fp);

    /* Calculate how many numbers come after the 29 numbers already used */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 29, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%d\n", "(size - 29");

    /* Print array  lien by line*/
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          printf("array[%d] == %d\n", i, array[i]);
      }

    /* Close file */  
    fclose(fp);

    /* End Program */
    return(0);
    }

Output:
4235474
array[0] == 3072
array[1] == 2048
array[2] == 1280
array[3] == 2816
array[4] == 1536
array[5] == 1280
array[6] == 1792
array[7] == 2304000
array[8] == 0
array[9] == 1969189747
array[10] == 1969189738
array[11] == 1800422248
array[12] == 4199072
array[13] == 4199072
array[14] == 0
array[15] == 4200832
array[16] == 6422240
array[17] == 6422296
array[18] == 6422476
array[19] == 1969213936
array[20] == 1750414460
array[21] == 1936749684
array[22] == 2033135418
array[23] == 1970566511
/* etcetera.... */
```

There are only supposed to be 7 numbers, not 4235474. And the array should not have 60 numbers stored in it, only 7. I've been staring at this code for days now and nothing seems to change the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Fills "str" character array with 29 characters from the file. */
fgets(str, 29, fp);
```

That comment lies. `fgets()` stops reading when it finds a newline. The following `fread` then reads where `fgets` left off, leading to surprising results.

You should also get in the habit of testing the return values of all the I/O functions. These often point you right where the problem is.

Then,

```
 printf("%d\n", "(size - 29");
```

you pass a pointer-to-char to a `%d` format, which explains the funny size value you see. This should be

```
printf("%d\n", size - 29);
```

If your compiler did not complain about this, crank up the warning level!

Next, `size = ftell(fp);` yields the size in units of bytes, not units of ints. If an int is 4 bytes, you loop far past the end of the array.

Comment: Even so, I have a SEEK_SET after that anyways.

Comment: @Holmsler No you haven't. It's fgets directly followed by fread.

Comment: @Holmsler Happens to the best of us :-)

Comment: I just moved it to after the SEEK_SET and the problem remains. :(

Comment: The `fread()` into a `int`-array is also quite suspicious, particularly because the file apparently contains non-binary data for `str`. The access of `array` beyond `array[19]` is obviously undefined.

Comment: Would it be possible for a file to be partly logical words and partly binary? This file shows up as squares on my notepad++ after the initial 29 characters.